# singleton class with non-default constructor

Tags: c++, class, constructor, singleton

I've got a `class` that needs to become a singleton. All good and fine only that it has a non-default constructor, i.e. it takes three arguments.
The best I could come up with is, to set the constuctor `private` and then provide some kind of `public` "setup" function.
Are there any better solutions? My work around so far looks something like - any ideas to improve this are welcome!

```
#include <iostream>

class singltn {
    private:
        static singltn *instance;
        int data;

        // Private constructor so that no objects can be created.
        singltn() {
            data = 0;
        }
        int _AA;
        int _BB;
        int _CC;
   public:
        static singltn *getInstance() {
            if (!instance)
                instance = new singltn;            

            return instance;
        }
        void setup(int AA, int BB, int CC) {
            _AA = AA;
            _BB = BB;
            _CC = CC;
        }

   int getData() {
      return this->data;
   }

   void setData(int data) {
      this -> data = data;
   }
   int getAA(){
       return this->_AA;
   }

};

//Initialize pointer to zero so that it can be initialized in first call to getInstance
singltn *singltn::instance = 0;

int main(){
    singltn *a = a->getInstance();
    a->setup(111,222,333);
    std::cout << "dat " << a->getData() << " _AA " << a-> getAA() << std::endl;
    a->setData(100);
    std::cout << "dat " << a->getData() << " _AA " << a-> getAA() << std::endl;  
    singltn *b = b->getInstance(); 
    std::cout << "dat " << b->getData() << " _AA " << a-> getAA() << std::endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: How will your singleton behave if it is used without having been set up?  It might be better to have a create/setup function that creates the instance and sets it up that must be called before it is used.  Also, your `getInstance` is not thread safe if the instance must be created (you could end up with multiple copies), although that probably isn't an issue for you.

Comment: `getInstance()` is public so why not pass in the parameters as in `getInstance(111,222,333)`? This seems obvious so maybe i'm missing something?

Comment: @bcperth `getInstance()` might be called from places where the config parameters are not available (I know I could use a prototype with default params - but that seemed a bit too "clumsy")

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm hm, yes, it won't be a problemin my instance butanyhow, using a `std::lock_guard<std::mutex>lockstd::lock_guard<std::mutex>lock(mtx)` on the 1st line in the constructor should take care of it, would you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapting [Steve's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52638626/7699037) to provide a setup function for the singleton class:

```
class Foo {
 public:
  static Foo& GetInstance() { return SetupInstance(-1, -1); }

  static Foo& SetupInstance(int a, int b) {
    static Foo foo(a, b);
    return foo;
  }

 private:
  Foo(int a, int b) {
    // ...
  }
};
```

As the constructor of the `static` singleton get's only called once, multiple calls to `SetupInstance` will not re-create a new object of `Foo`, but always return the object which was created at the first call.

Comment: Using this code, each call to getInstance will change the values of the object back to -1 -1, which is doubtfully desirable

Comment: @YoavKlein That's not true. The cosntructor of `Foo` will only be called once, as it is static. Every subsequent call to `SetupInstance` or `GetInstance` will not execute the constructor of `Foo` and thus, the values of the object will not change

Comment: The constructor will be called once, but SetupInstance will be called each time. And supposing that SetupInstance sets some variables, it will always set them to -1 -1, no?

Comment: @YoavKlein Yes, `SetupInstance` will be called each time, but the member variables are set in the constructor, not in `SetupInstance` and thus, they will only be set once, namely the first time `SetupInstance` is called which is the only time the constructor will be called.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static factory/getter function that calls a private constructor. Something like this:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static Foo& GetInstance() {
        static Foo foo(param1, param2);
        return foo;
    }
private:
    Foo(int a, int b) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Of course, that requires your factory function to somehow know the parameters somehow.

Comment: but in orer to get `param1` & `param2` in there, you still need to have some kind of  `setup()` function - only here it is required to called beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use real singleton (which handles creation + unique instance + global access), and adapt it:

```
class MyClass
{
private:
    int data = 0;
    int _AA;
    int _BB;
    int _CC;

    static std::unique_ptr<MyClass> uniqueInstance;

    MyClass(int AA, int BB, int CC) : _AA(AA), _BB(BB), _CC(CC) {}

    MyClass(const MyClass&) = delete;
    MyClass& operator =(const MyClass&) = delete;

public:

    static void Create(int AA, int BB, int CC)
    {
        // if (uniqueInstance) throw std::runtime_error("Call it only once");
        uniqueInstance = std::make_unique<MyClass>(AA, BB, CC);
    }

    static MyClass& GetInstance()
    {
         if (!uniqueInstance) throw std::runtime_error("Call Create before");
         return *uniqueInstance;
    }

    int getData() const { return this->data; }
    void setData(int data) { this->data = data; }
    int getAA() const { return _AA; }
};

std::unique_ptr<MyClass> MyClass::uniqueInstance;

int main(){
    MyClass::Create(111, 222, 333);
    auto& a = MyClass::GetInstance();
    std::cout << "dat " << a.getData() << " _AA " << a.getAA() << std::endl;
    a.setData(100);
    std::cout << "dat " << a.getData() << " _AA " << a.getAA() << std::endl;  
}
```